# Why do I get a ReferenceError when using audio in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, audio, settimeout

I want to schedule an audio play. Why this code returns a ReferenceError for a?

```
function playSound()
{
  var a = new Audio("mp3/win.mp3");
  setTimeout("a.play('mp3/win.mp3');", 1000);
}
playSound();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `a` variable definition to the global context:

```
var a = new Audio("mp3/win.mp3");
function playSound()
{
  setTimeout("a.play('mp3/win.mp3');",1000);
}
playSound();
```

Or use `function` notation instead of `code` notation

```
function playSound()
{
  var a = new Audio("mp3/win.mp3");
  setTimeout(function() {
    a.play('mp3/win.mp3');
  },1000);
}
playSound();
```

The cause of the issue, I think, is in the eval-like nature of setTimeout `code` notation. Let's see what MDN says on `setTimeout` [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> Passing a string instead of a function to setTimeout() suffers from
>   the same hazards as using eval.

And then on `eval` [(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> If you use the eval function indirectly, by invoking it via a
>   reference other than eval, as of ECMAScript 5 it works in the global
>   scope rather than the local scope. This means, for instance, that
>   function declarations create global functions, and that the code being
>   evaluated doesn't have access to local variables within the scope
>   where it's being called.

And `setTimeout("a.play('mp3/win.mp3')", 1000)` is like an indirect `eval` call.

Comment: Yea. I forgot the quotes. still I get ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: I guess it's a closure issue as changing it to    
    setTimeout(function(){a.play('mp3/win.mp3');},1000); works too.

Comment: @OMGsh Think, I've got the root of problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the string notation on `setTimeout` it's not being treated as if it was a function as you would imagine (since the first parameter is typically a function). Instead it's treated as if it was a script that's being run whenever the amount of milliseconds has passed.

So it's as if it were adding:

```
<script>a.play('mp3/win.mp3');</script>
```

Every 1000 milliseconds.

Since `a` is not global (its part of the function that does the setTimeout), then it can't see it hence the ReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a string as the argument to `setTimeout`, it's executed in the global scope, so it can't access local variables. Use a function argument.

```
function playSound()
{
    var a = new Audio("mp3/win.mp3");
    setTimeout(() => a.play('mp3/win.mp3'),1000);
}
playSound();
```